# Amazon S3 + Cloudfront VS Rackspace CloudFiles

Tags: amazon-s3, rackspace, amazon-cloudfront

I know this question came up lot of time on the internet , But I couldn't find any latest updates on this . So I gathered the information what I found and putting here and have few questions on it . Could some one please answer them ?

**Some note :-** I am using other third party provider for my website ( social networking website) and going to use amazon or rackspace for photo uploading and for storing all my static content .

**Number of Locations :-** Amazon I see 40 locations world wide CDN centers from their website . http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/ . Rackspace uses 213 of Akamai's edge locations.

**Customer support :-** Amazon ,we have to pay extra 100$ for customer support . Rackspace it comes with free

**Folder Structure :-** Amazon has good folder structure management , we can create buckets and use them . But Rackspace lacks this feature

**Free Ties :-** Amazon has free tier where we can use register it for free and use it . But rackspace on the other hand I couldn't find any free tire to use it .AM I missing any thing here ..

**Price :-** This is where I am getting confused . I heard amazon charges less , But after using their website and doing calculation I got some thing different results . Could some one throw some light If I am missing some thing ?

RackSpace price :- 172.88

http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/files/pricing/

amazon price :- 282.55 ( Plus 100$ for support)

http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html

Please see the screen shot below .My calculation is for 500 GB storage and 1024 GB Out per month

[image]

Comment: Your CloudFiles calculation doesn't appear to include of the Akamai CDN's costs at $0.12/GB. You shouldn't need AWS support if you're just using S3+CloudFront, and you can turn it on for just one month (at the $50 level, too) if you do.

Comment: Thank You ceejayoz for the info . I couldn't find out separate cost for Akamai CDN's cost on their site . Let me have a look at again . What they mentioned is Cloud Files Includes storage + CDN

Comment: I am looking at this URL http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/files/pricing/ . The mentioned Bandwidth from the data center to the CDN edge location" costs no additional charges